# How can conditionally render some text in React without using an else branch?

Tags: reactjs

I'm a front-end newbie. I am messing around with some React code in `MyFile.tsx`. This is what I have:

```
<p>
    {(2 > 1) ? "goodbye world" : "hello world"}
</p>
```

Happily, this renders "goodbye world". Of course it does.

But I want to use a simple if -- without an else branch. How can I do that?

I tried the following, but it gave me a syntax error:

```
<p>
    {if (2 > 1) ("goodbye world")}
</p>
```

Comment: just use `&&` like this `{2 > 1 && "goodbye world"}`. See [https://reactpatterns.com/#conditional-rendering](https://reactpatterns.com/#conditional-rendering)

Comment: As @Mushroomator wrote, you can use ```&&```. Due to the way it works, if the first statement is true, the text will render (as it is truthy). If the first statement is false, the text won't even be evaluated as the expression as a whole is already false. You can also just return an empty string using the ternary operator, as such ```2 > 1 ? "goodbye world" : ""```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html):

> You may embed expressions in JSX by wrapping them in curly braces. This includes the JavaScript logical `&&` operator. It can be handy for conditionally including an element:

```
{(2 > 1) && ("Goodbye World")}
```

This is essentially just a ternary operator without the short circuit.